# Foreach Multidimensional Array formatting grouping

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, formatting

I have made a function which outputs data through a multidimensional array and as far as I have done it all data with conditional output, now remains the problem that I want to format the output data.

Here is the target where I want with the code ... See picture what was made with pure HTML:

[image: Image: HTML Formating]

Now I try to convert it into PHP by extract data from a repeater field. Thats fine, but I would like to group and formating it.

As follows:

As soon as the name of the month and the number of years are released, I would like to group their time data into three groups, which means that the maximum of three times is enclosed in one HTML and then the next one follows until a new month section appears and so that only the before last element has a Seperator "|".

Here is the Code:

```
function rp_all_info_termine() {
$termine = rp_get_all_termine();

$output          = '';
$i               = 0;
$is_same_month   = false;
$monthname       = '';
foreach ( $termine as $keys => $values ) {
    foreach ( $values as $key => $value ) {
        $get_date        = preg_replace( '/\s+/', '', $value[ 'title' ] );
        $get_monthname   = rp_get_month_name( $get_date );
        $get_year        = rp_get_year( $get_date );
        $get_time        = trim( $value[ 'description' ] );
        $get_weekday     = rp_get_weekday( $get_date );

        if ( rp_check_date( $get_date ) == '-1' || rp_check_date( $get_date ) == '0' ) {
            unset( $key );
            continue;
        }

        if ( $get_monthname != $monthname ) {
            $monthname   = '<h3>' . esc_html( $get_monthname );
            $year        = '&nbsp;' . esc_html( $get_year ) . '</h3>';
        } else {
            $monthname   = null;
            $year        = null;
        }

        $output  .= $monthname;
        $output  .= $year;
        $output  .= esc_html( $get_date );
        $output  .= esc_html( $get_weekday );
        $output  .= esc_html( $get_time ).'&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;';

        $monthname = $get_monthname;

        $i++;
    }
}
return $output;
}
```

Here are my result:

[image: Image: PHP Loop Format]

**MY EDIT:**

Thanks to your answer i have made it, but now is the only unsolved issue with the seperator... this what i have changed:

```
    if ( $get_monthname != $monthname ) {
            $i   = 0;
            $monthname   = '<h3><strong>' . esc_html( $get_monthname );
            $year        = '&nbsp;' . esc_html( $get_year ) . '</strong></h3>';
        } else {
            $monthname   = null;
            $year        = null;
        }

        if ( $i == 3 ) {
            $output .= '<br>';
        }
```

With the seperator i have a try to solve is in similar way here is the result:

```
    if ( $i >= 1 ) {
            $output .= '&nbsp;|&nbsp;';
        }
```

[image]

But i would to place the seperator in the last element of the three like so:

[image]

Comment: Use a counter that you set to `0` when you start a new month, and add `<br>` whenever the counter is a multiple of `3`.

Comment: Thanks this worked, but now the only left unsolved issue is with the seperator. I have edit my question. thanks for your help

Comment: When the count is a multiple of 3, print `<br>` *instead of* `|`.